# Unit test for Expression tree in c#

Tags: c#, expression, mstest, xunit, linqkit

How do I write a unit test for a Expression tree in C#.

I have this class which needs to be tested. This method returns a Expression tree and also gets one as a parameter.

code:

```
public ExpressionStarter<SpecFinderDataModel> DoSearch(bool status, string searchValue, ExpressionStarter<SpecFinderDataModel> predicate)
{
    var localPredicate = predicate;
    if (status == false)
    {
        var searchTerms = searchValue.Split(' ').ToList().ConvertAll(x => x.ToLower());
        localPredicate = localPredicate.Or(s => searchTerms.Any(srch => s.ProductID.ToLower().Contains(srch)));
        localPredicate = localPredicate.Or(s => searchTerms.Any(srch => s.ISBN13.ToLower().Contains(srch)));
        localPredicate = localPredicate.Or(s => searchTerms.Any(srch => s.Title.ToLower().Contains(srch)));
    }
    return localPredicate;
}
```

Any advice would be helpful. Thanks.

**Update #1**
I have used LinqKit for ExpressionStarter

Comment: Compile the result Expression to `Func` and verify the result with relevant input

Comment: The problem is I have written unit test for basic concepts, but not for advanced like using Expression. I have no idea. Could you please point me where to look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shall be simple, though I will use the `Expression<Func<SpecFinderDataModel,bool>>` instead of LinqKit APIs, which is used internally, In the `DoSearch` method, you need `Expression<Func<SpecFinderDataModel,bool>>` as input, based on the method assuming following as the definition of the type `SpecFinderDataModel`

```
public class SpecFinderDataModel
{
    public string ProductID {get; set;}

    public string ISBN13 {get; set;}

    public string Title {get; set;}
}
```

Now you need to simply test various options, as done in regular unit test, a sample:

```
   // Initial Expression value constant false is the result
   Expression<Func<SpecFinderDataModel, bool>> expr = c => false;

    // SpecFinderDataModel Object
    var sfd = new SpecFinderDataModel
    {
     ISBN13 = "",
     ProductID = "Test A B C",
     Title = ""
    }

    // Call DoSearch and supply the sfd for testing
    var result = DoSearch(false,"Test",expr).Compile()(sfd);

    // Assert the result in the unit test to understand 
    Assert.True(result,true);
```

Like this based on combinations of the `DoSearch` parameters and test object `sfd`, you can create any number of unit test cases to test your code

Comment: You are awesome. it worked like a charm. Thank you @Mrinal

Comment: Welcome, glad it helped